# Como hago que este codigo debe de ser bloqueante en JS?

Tags: javascript, callback, async

Tengo este codigo en  `javascript` bloqueante, y como estoy comenzando a aprender sobre  `callbacks`,  `promesas` y  `async-await` no se como hacer para que cuando ingreso a `localhost:3000/about`  realice la iteracion de 100.000 vueltas y que al mismo tiemo carga `localhost:3000/` sin demoras en resumen que sea no bloqueante

```
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/") {
    res.write("Welcome to / the server");
    return res.end("Index Page");
  }


  await iteracion(req, res);
  res.end("Not found");

});

function iteracion(req, res) {

  if (req.url === "/about") {

    for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      console.log(Math.random() * i);
    }
    return res.end("About Page");

  }
}

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la finalidad de tantas iteraciones?

Comment: Tantas iteraciones pueden sobrecargar el servidor, ten en cuenta que JavaScript está supuesto para ejecutarse en un solo hilo, eso quiere decir que una sola rama del CPU cargará con todo el trabajo, que no podrá ser distribuido de manera equitativa. Para abordar esto, se suelen usar métodos más eficientes del lado del servidor que iterar 100000 veces, pero para ayudarte mejor necesitaría saber la finalidad de tantas iteraciones.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que cuando un solo hilo del CPU se sobrecarga debido a las iteraciones que estás haciendo, esto puede significar que estarás tapando el hilo principal hasta que terminen las tareas que estás haciendo. Que el hilo principal esté tapado o bloqueado, el servidor NO podrá procesar más datos hasta que la ejecución de las iteraciones termine, esto sería un problema para tu servidor, además que esto usará una cantidad significativa de recursos, lo que puede hacer que incluso después de la ejecución de las iteraciones, el servidor estará lento ocasionando un _"Cuello de botella"_.

Comment: Todo esto explica por qué cuando entras a la ruta del servidor que ejecuta las iteraciones, esta demora en cargar, porque JavaScript NO se ejecutará en múltiples hilos, sino que esperará a que terminen las iteraciones, y luego interpretará el resto de tu código.

Comment: Voy a responder por el OP, ya que creo haber entendido su situación. El tiene 2 endpoints uno pesado y otro liviano, resulta que si entra al pesado el liviano queda bloqueado. Las iteraciones son solo un ejemplo, bien podría ser una consulta pesada sobre una base de datos

Comment: Exacto @Yussef esas eran mis intenciones!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonzalo: cuál es la finalidad de la función "about"? Es simular una operación pesada? Porque no lo está haciendo. Es funcionar como parte del router? Eso sí lo está haciendo y no debiera ser así.

Separemos las cosas. La función encargada de hacer las veces de router debiera ser la única que evalúa `req` y llama métodos de `res`

```
const server = http.createServer( async (req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/") {
    res.write("Welcome to / the server");
    return res.end("Index Page");
  }

  if (req.url === "/about") {
    await iteracion(req, res);

    return res.end("About Page");
  }

  res.end("Not found");

});
```

Ahora lo que necesitas es una función que realmente simule una demora. Hoy estás intentando hacer eso con un bucle for tradicional y no te funciona.

Resulta que ese tipo de `for`, así como `forEach` y `map` pasan por alto el uso de `await`. Si dentro del bucle vas a tener una llamada asíncrona entonces debieras usar `for..of`.

```
  for(let i of Array(100000).fill(Math.random())) {
     await console.log(i)
  }
```

Eso te garantiza una buena espera. Pero en tu caso, cambiando a `for..of` sólo te quedas con un `console.log(Math.random(i))` que sigue siendo síncrono. En otras palabras, sólo estarías generando un tiempo de espera por la naturaleza de las promesas (que entran en el stack al tick siguiente) y porque estás copando el stack con cómputo que no necesitas.

Yo te sugeriría que usaras un helper que me hice hace unos años y es cómodo para estas pruebas:

```
async function waitFor(delay = 500) {
      return new Promise(res=> setTimeout(res,delay))
}
```

De manera que podrías decir exactamente cuánta espera quieres simular en `iteracion` en vez de fundir tu computador a puro console.log

```
const server = http.createServer( async (req, res) => {
   if (req.url === "/") {
     res.write("Welcome to / the server");
     return res.end("Index Page");
   }

  if (req.url === "/about") {
     await waitFor(1000);
     return res.end("About Page");
   }

   res.end("Not found");

 });
```

Por supuesto que puedes llamar al `waitFor` en tu función `iteracion`, eso es cosa tuya. Pero en este nuevo escenario al menos no necesitas pasar `req` ni `res`, que es un code smell.

Comment: hola! muchas gracias! creo que entendi ahora la explicacion del porque con un bucle for no iba a funcionar nunca. Gracias

Comment: el bucle `for..of` sí espera una promesa. Pero lo que estabas haciendo era simular una espera ejecutando una tarea demandante en CPU. Es mala idea para probar un concepto. Si querías simular la demora en la llamada a un API o la ejecución de un child process no necesitas freir tu CPI para simularlo